# Find the range of absolute values with inequality and two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

Given $|x - y| < 1 $, what is the range covered in inequality? then update the inequality such that the range covers only $0$ & $1$. $(x ≥ 0 \land y ≥ 0 \land X, Y \in \mathbb{Z})$

1. We can find the range by solving the inequality as $ -1 < x - y < 1 $, so the range covered is $(-1, 1)$, is it correct?
2. if I want to update the inequality such that the range covers only $0$ & $1$ as $|x - y| \in [0, 1]$, not sure how to approach this part.
   Should I write a system of equations to represent it?

Thank you.

Comment: Let consider $x=100$ and $y=99.5$ then $|x-y|<1$.

Comment: I updated the question to give one more constraint, X and Y are integers @user

Answer (score 0):

We have the following cases

- $x-y>0 \implies x - y < 1$ that is

$$x-1<y<x$$

- $x-y<0 \implies -x + y < 1$ that is

$$x<y<x+1$$

then trace the inequalities in the $xy-$plane.